# Markov Process w/ a non-stochastic matrix?

Tags: probability, matrix, markov-process, graph-theory, transition-matrix

I've come across a problem which at first appeared to be a markov process however the transition matrix of the graph is non-stochastic. That is, the probabilities among edges *leaving* a node do not sum to 1. However,the probabilities on edges *entering* the node do sum to 1. Therefore the transpose of the transition matrix IS stochastic.

I've built up a model in excel and noticed a few properties of this "transpose markovian process":

1. all nodes reach the same steady state value.
2. the steady state *is* dependent on the initial state (unlike a markov process).
3. the steady state value can be computed as S<sub>0</sub> x M<sup>T</sup> (the initial state vector times the transpose of the markovian steady state vector... obtained by transposing the transition matrix and solving as a markov process).

My question is this: **Is there a name for such a process?** In searching for it I've found it to be beyond obscure, so my hope is some well-informed human can catalyze me with some search terms.

Comment: $P(\text{staying}) = 1 - P(\text{leaving})$. A Markov process can stay in the same state for many iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no new name for the processes you mentioned. Markov processes can be defined with row-stochastic or column-stochastic matrices. The choice is only a matter of *convention*.

If the entries of each row sum up to 1, then the stationary state S0 satisfies $S_0=S_0.M$, otherwise it satisfies $M.S_0=S_0$ .